# how to add& remove overlay image using gridcell index

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, grid, imageview

here is my code

```
-(void)gridCell:(GridCell *)gCell didSelectImageAtIndex:(NSInteger)index imagSize:(CGRect )frameSize
{
            UIImage *img=[UIImage imageNamed:@"Overlay"];
            UIImageView *imgView=[[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:frameSize];
            imgView.image=img;
            [_scrPage addSubview:imgView];
            [self.view addSubview:_scrPage];
 }
```

please help me how to remove overlay ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By "overlay" I assume you mean the mean the `UIImageView` you added the `_srcPage`?  Have you retained some sort of reference to that view?  If so, then all you need to do is `[imgView removeFromSuperview];`  If not, you need to find out how you can get a reference to that specific view.